# Openness of the set of injective functions in $C(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ be equipped with the topology of compact convergence (or equivalently the compact-open topology).  Then, is the subset $\left\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}):
\text{$f$ injective} 
\right\}$ an open subset therein?

Comment: You can easily find a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ each $[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ with $f_n(0)=0, f_n(1)=1$, each non-injective, and with $f_n(x)\rightarrow x$ uniformly.  Now extend each function to $\mathbb R$ by defining it as the identity outside $[0,1]$.  This gives a sequence of non-injectives which converges uniformly on compacta to an injective.  So the complement of your set is not closed.

Comment: A continuous function on the reals is injective iff it is either strictly decreasing or strictly increasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Matthew's post here we go:

Let $f_n(x)\triangleq \left|\frac{x}{n+1}\cos(\frac{x-1}{n})\right| + \left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right) x$ and $f(x)=x$ and $\sup_{x \in [0,1] }\|f_n(x)-f(x)\| \in \mathscr{O}(n^{-1})$.

This provides a counter example on $C((0,1))$ and then just use the homeomorphism:
$$
\begin{aligned}
C(0,1) &\rightarrow C(\mathbb{R})\\
f &\mapsto f \circ \frac{1}{1+ \exp(-x)},
\end{aligned}
$$
to get the conclusion. (Note, that is preserves the class of injective maps).

Answer (score 12):

A simpler example is $f_\epsilon(x)=x^3+\epsilon x$ which is injective iff $\epsilon\geq 0$.

Answer (score 11):

I think that this is a kind of question (which is not research level and) which should not be answered by a counterexample but by an explanation: What would it mean that, e.g., the identity map is an interior point of the set of injective continuous functions? There should be a compact interval $[-n,n]$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that any function $f\in C(\mathbb R)$ with $|f(x)-x|<\varepsilon$ for $x\in [-n,n]$ is injective. This is absurd because you have no condition at all outside $[-n,n]$.  But also inside the interval one can easily modify the graph of the identity to get a non-injective function which $\varepsilon$-close to the identity.